# Basic database association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am attempting to associate 2 models - `Athletes` and `Results`

They have the following fields:
Athletes - `:name :year :gender`
Results - `:name :event :performance`

I have added `belongs_to :athlete` to `results.rb` & added `has_many :results` to `athletes.rb`

I would like to use the :name attribute to act as the primary key used to associate the two models as the intention is for all athletes to be uploaded initially and then just use the results input for the remainder of the season.

I have edited the `results_controller` to the following:

```
def create
#this was the initial code....
#@result = Result.new(params[:result])

# This is the new code to try set up an association
@athlete = Athlete.where('name = ?', 'Peter')
@result = @athlete.results.create(params[:result])

respond_to do |format|
  if @result.save
    format.html { redirect_to @result, notice: 'Result was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @result, status: :created, location: @result }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @result.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This however produces the error `undefined method 'results' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x36a2b28>`. I was also hoping to use the line `@athlete = Athlete.where("name = ?", params[:name])` however it keeps yielding a NULL parameter value...

Is anyone able to point me in the correct direction please?

**Extra information:**
Results migration

```
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration   def change
 create_table :results do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.string :event
   t.decimal :performance

   t.timestamps
 end

#add in new line here   
add_index :results, :name

end end
```

Athletes migration

```
class CreateAthletes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :athletes do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :year
      t.string :gender

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Result.rb:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :athlete
 end
```

Athlete.rb

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :results
 end
```

Comment: Please paste the model code in for Athlete. thx

Comment: Just added, thanks for taking a look Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Athlete.where('name = ?', 'Peter')` returns ActiveRecord::Relation object. Either use

```
Athlete.where('name = ?', 'Peter').first
```

or the dynamic find method

```
Athlete.find_by_name('Peter')
```

**Edit**

Also make sure you add `t.references :athlete` to your results table.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately both these yield the error - `unknown attribute: athlete_id`

Comment: OK this now seems to be making a huge difference thanks! Final question in that case is... I would like to identify the athlete using the information typed into the "New Result" form (consists of name, event, performance).  However, using `@athlete = Athlete.where('name = ?', params[:name]).first` doesn't work (i get a NULL value).  When I view the server log i have the following - `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"I3o1uXM+apeQzOs6iesPeWq2KboVNJ87VDVMd2DIIZM=",
 "result"=>{"name"=>"Peter",
 "event"=>"200m",
 "performance"=>"22.4567"},
 "commit"=>"Create Result"}`  How can I call :name?

Comment: Bingo - thanks a lot for all your help (and everyone else) - it has solved the problem and also helped me to understand what is going on thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your results table needs to store the athlete_id.

```
create_table :results do |t|
 t.references :athlete
 t.string :name
 t.string :event
 t.decimal :performance
 t.timestamps
end
```

The references will create the foreign key association using the rails conventions (which in this case is athlete_id)

Comment: Toby thanks for this, also exactly what I needed but accepted the first answer received.  Thanks for your time